# Understand Umat UmatUsagesFlags flags options

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, mat

I'm trying to understand the differences between UmatUsagesFlags flags:

I'm looking for a Umat object that can hold the memory both on the host and device

(Is there something like managed memory in CUDA?)

```
USAGE_ALLOCATE_HOST_MEMORY
```

Allocate the memory on the host

```
USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY
```

Allocate the memory on the device

```
USAGE_ALLOCATE_SHARED_MEMORY
```

What does is this means in OpenCL scope?

```
USAGE_ALLOCATE_HOST_MEMORY || USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY
```

What does is this means for Umat object ?

Let say I want to hold the memory both on device and host at the same time, does this means that I'm going to have to hold both Umat and Mat objects and convert the memory from host to device and vice versa ?